# Camaro : Module not found: Can't resolve xxxx

Tags: node.js, npm, serverless

using Camaro npm package to transform XML in Server-less framework lambda project and getting error when running sls offline command -

Module not found for asm2wasm, env, global

WebAssembly module is included in initial chunk.
This is not allowed, because WebAssembly download and compilation must happen asynchronous.
Add an async splitpoint (i. e. import()) somewhere between your entrypoint and the WebAssembly module: